# Does this fractal mapping have a name?

Tags: functions, terminology, fractals, iterated-function-system, ternary-expansion

I was playing with a mapping $f:[0,1] \to \text{Sierpinski's Triangle}$, and I'd like to know if there's a name for this kind of thing. [It's a lot like playing the [chaos game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game) in reverse order.]

**The process**:

1. Label the vertices of the Sierpinski Triangle (ST) with the digits $0$, $1$ and $2$.
2. Begin with an arbitrary point $P$ in the largest empty triangle of ST (from [this construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle#/media/File:Sierpinski_triangle_evolution.svg)).
3. Take a real number $x$ between $0$ and $1$, and write its *infinite* ternary expansion. [If a number terminates after finitely many digits, continue it with infinitely many zeros.]
4. Start reading the digits of the expansion from left-to-right, and for each digit, move point $P$ into the next-smallest empty triangle "in the direction" of the vertex with that number. ["In the direction" here just means down-left, down-right or up.]
5. Take the limiting location of point $P$ as $f(x)$.

**Example**: Let $x=0.4 = 0.\overline{1012}_3$

Point $P$ starts in the center triangle. The first digit **1** moves $P$ into the center triangle that is down to the right (since vertex $1$ is down to the right). The next digit **0** moves $P$ down to the left (since vertex $0$ is down to the left). The next digit **1** moves $P$ down to the right, then **2** moves it up, etc. See the GeoGebra animation below:

[image: The Sierpinski triangle with a point starting in the center and moving according to the description given in the paragraph above.]

Similarly, the number $0.5 = 0.\overline{1}_3$ would be at vertex **1**, and $\frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline{3} = 0.1\overline{0}_3$ would be midway between vertices **0** and **1**.

**More Info**. It seems every $x$ should have a unique point on the fractal, unless we allow it to be written in two equivalent ways where one ends in an infinite number of $2$'s or $1$'s. [Notice that writing $\frac{1}{3}=0.0\overline{2}_3$ also puts $\frac{1}{3}$ midway between vertices **0** and **2**.] Similarly, appending an infinite number of $0$'s at the end of an expansion means that a point on the fractal won't have a unique number mapping to it. [The number $\frac{1}{6} = 0.0\overline{1}_3$ is also at the midpoint between vertices **0** and **1**.]

Here's a [GeoGebra manipulative](https://www.geogebra.org/m/zwdyvgmu) showing the function from $x=0$ to $x=1$ in steps of $0.001$. [Press the play button at bottom left.] Even in huge steps of $0.001$, it's easy to see lots of discontinuities where a ternary number is getting, say, a large sequence of $2$'s -- the "next" number mapped suddenly jumps to a $1$ in the previous digit.

Again, I thought this was silly and fun, but I figured it might have been looked at in the past and have a name.

Comment: If understood correctly - "Random walks"?

Comment: This has possibly 2 points per number due to different ternary expansions being equal.  Compare with e.g. Hilbert curve which has possibly multiple numbers per point.

Comment: @agent_cracker103 Since the steps taken for a given number are determined by its ternary digits, maybe "deterministic walk"?

Comment: Regarding the Ill definition - I guess a tail of 2s isn't allowed and then it's well definied.
Also @NickC I guess this map is one among many examples of unnamed mathematical objects.
It is continues and thus it proves the Sierpinski's Triangle is a closed set. Probably some topologist used it in some book and named it as per their wish (idk I didn't encounter one).